# C++ function Parameter passing

Tags: c++

I have one function

```
int C_MORPHO_Device::Capture(C_MORPHO_TemplateList& o_x_Template);  

I C_MORPHO_TemplateList::GetTemplate  ( UC  i_uc_indexTemplate,  
  T_MORPHO_TYPE_TEMPLATE &  o_uc_typTemplate,  
  UL &  o_ul_lenTemplate,  
  PUC &  o_puc_dataTemplate,  
  UC &  i_uc_dataIndex   
 )
```

How to pass the `o_x_Template` as a parameter to my `Capture` function.

```
C_MORPHO_Device Capture;  
Capture.Capture(C_MORPHO_TemplateList& o_x_Template);
```

Comment: You pass it and that's it, what's the problem?

Comment: "I have one function" - that's two functions. "How to pass the o_x_Template as a parameter to my Capture function?" - exactly as it is declared.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1):

You probably only need to write

```
C_MORPHO_Device Capture;  
Capture.Capture(o_x_Template);
```

The function expects a parameter passed as a reference, which does not require any specific syntax decoration, assuming `o_x_Template` is indeed a `C_MORPHO_TemplateList`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
C_MORPHO_Device Capture;  
C_MORPHO_TemplateList o_x_Template;
Capture.Capture(o_x_Template);
```

When you call a function, you need to pass in the real object, instead of declaration.